# NSFetchedResultsController controllerWillChangeContent not called for relationship changes

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have iOS application which uses core data database and im using NSFetchedResultsController for populate a tableview.
Im using entity named "Catalog" to populate tablview and i have thumbnail image stored in entity Named "Image" and i store image as NSData in a property of image entity, im updating that thumbnail image after populating the tableview but any of bellow methods not called.

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- But when i change a properties of "Catalog" entity itself those methods called.

## Informations of My Entities

## Catalog(Entity)

Attributes

title <= String
  nid   <= String (my primary key field)
  some few attributes

### Relationships

Relationship :thumbImage,
Destination  :Image,
Inverse      :catalog,

## Image(Entity)

Attributes
  fid   <= String (my primary key field),
  image <= Image Data field

### Relationships

Relationship :catalog,
Destination  :Catalog,
Inverse      :thumbImage

Comment: Have u set the delegate? e.g typically like this `_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;`

Comment: yes i have set delegate, Delegate methods are called if when change of a attributes of catalog entity problem with changing relationship's attribute.

Comment: That is a known restriction of NSFetchedResultsController, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533849/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-relationship-not-updating.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your `Image` entity:

```
//Not tested
- (void) setImage:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.catalog willChangeValueForKey:@"thumbImage"]
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:data forKey:@"image"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"image"];
    [self.catalog didChangeValueForKey:@"thumbImage"];
}
```

Comment: The lines:  [self.catalog willChangeValueForKey:@"thumbImage"];,[self.catalog didChangeValueForKey:@"thumbImage"];   not calls to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate.   help please!

Comment: if this does not work, try adding an integer property to `Catalog` and increment it then the image change content (sort of 'needRefresh' property)

Comment: I can't test this at the moment. will try to get back to you when I'll have more time.