# Insert predicate for B in predicate for A linked with relationship to B

Tags: ios, objective-c, magicalrecord

Entity A have one-to-many relationship with entity B called `points`.
I have NSPredicate for B.
I need to fetch objects of A that have any object of B that satisfies this predicate. 
How can i do that with one NSPredicate?

I can't do that in two separate operations (first find B, then use them to find A), because i need to keep NSFetchedResultsController for A which must react (call callbacks `controllerWillChangeContent`, `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` and `controllerDidChangeContent`) when any object of B is added/changed/removed.

Another note - i getting those predicate on B from other class and i don't know what it contains. Therefore i can't manually insert it in predicate on A.

Answer (score 0):

If your predicate on B is (for example)

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"someProp == %@", someValue]
```

then the predicate to fetch all A objects that have any B object satisfying this property
would be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY points.someProp == %@", someValue]
```

The fetched results controller will track changes to the `points` property of A
(adding or removing B objects). However it will not track changes to the properties of
the B objects. The reason is that an FRC does not track changes to related objects, compare
[NSFetchedResultsController with relationship not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533849/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-relationship-not-updating).

Comment: It's right, but i getting those predicate on B from other class and i don't know what it contains. So i can work only with NSPredicate object. Thanks for answer anyway.